# force browser refresh when loading pages

Tags: wordpress, caching

In WordPress, we are using W3 Total Cache, along with aMember (a membership program). We have W3TC configured to not cache most of the member pages for aMember users. The rest of the site (articles, etc) uses W3TC.

We are attempting to have a simple login/signup/logout button in the header in the whole site. If user is logged out, link says signin/login. If user is logged out, link says logout.

We have it all set up - the header links are coded conditionally in the correct way. But when a user logs in or logs out and goes to a page in site that uses W3TC, the link doesn't display correctly. If they are logged in, sometimes the link will say login/signup.

This can be remedied by a simple page refresh (a hard refresh isn't even necessary). The refresh works at displaying the accurate links, but of course, we don't want user to have to refresh page to see things accurately.

Is there a method that can refresh page when users arrives on a page, so they will see accurate links?

Or even better, when a user moves from one page to another, using a link, a code in the link forces page refresh of the page they are going to. This way, we could code this in to happen only for membership users.

We tried adding the following in the head with no success:

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

Here is a page on our site we are attempting to have this feature:
https://www.lifeleap.org/grow/

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Hi There simple html5 to autofocus on your field like this

`<input id="fname" type="text" name="fname" autofocus>`

[Devo](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autofocus.asp)

Other using jQuery  like this

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $( "#fname" ).focus();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We are attempting to refresh the whole WordPress page, or at least a widget on a page. I see the first example you mentioned is good for a form, and there are no forms on our page. The second example you mentions looks better. Can you give an example of how I might apply this to a div container, or ever better, a class? Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: Our logout button is only a link, not an actual form button. Do you have a suggestion as to how I can apply autofocus to a link, over even a div or class? I've seen here where it can be done, but I'm not able to find a working example of how to do it: http://api.jquery.com/focus/